# Web Socket with SQLite db and Dash Plotly - Binance stream data

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

Good day. Following tutorial using websockets with a SQlite db (aiosqlite), that fetches realtime data from binance. I have 2 apps running:
1- data.py - which runs the db connection and loads the data
2- app2.py - which is essentially the front-end to access the data and display the data realtime.

the issue I am experiencing is that when I run app2.py (although I see the data downloading) with print (data). The ticker information is not updating dynamically. It's only returning a single value. The return data statement is meant to return the first and last objects from the tuple.Herewith the code:

```
data.py

from websockets import connect
import asyncio
import sys
import aiosqlite
import sqlite3
import json

### create cursor connection to obtain data

conn = sqlite3.connect("./data.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trades")
cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE trades(
                id int PRIMARY KEY,
                time int,
                quantity int,
               price float) """)

cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX index_time ON trades(time)")

conn.commit()

conn.close()

url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade"

async def save_down(url):

    
    async with connect(url) as websocket:

        trades_buffer =[] ### create an empty list to append each trade

        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            data = json.loads(data) ### binance sends data as str object - hence convert to dictionary
            trades_buffer.append((data['a'], data['T'], data['q'], data['p'])) ### pass in as tuple

            print(data)

            if len(trades_buffer) > 10:
                
                print("Writing to DB")

                async with aiosqlite.connect("./data.db") as db:

                    await db.executemany("""INSERT INTO trades(id, time, quantity, price)
                                         VALUES(?,?,?,?)""", trades_buffer)
                    await db.commit()

                trades_buffer = []
            

asyncio.run(save_down(url))
```

```
app2.py

from dash import html, dcc, Output, Input, Dash, State, callback
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import sqlite3
from dash_extensions import WebSocket


update_frequency = 200 ### in milliseconds


app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(id="price-ticker"),
    dcc.Interval(id="update", interval = update_frequency),
    ])

@app.callback(
        Output("price-ticker", "children"),
        Input("update", "n_intervals"),
    )

def update_data(intervals):

    connection = sqlite3.connect("./data.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    data = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM trades ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10").fetchall()

    print(data)
 

    return data[0][3]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

````
print data:

* Serving Flask app 'app2'
 * Debug mode: on
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
[(2718642124, 1696657970443, 0.00052, 27893.49), (2718642123, 1696657969932, 0.01642, 27893.48), (2718642122, 1696657969487, 0.00035, 27893.49), (2718642121, 1696657969188, 0.00044, 27893.49), (2718642120, 1696657969146, 0.00022, 27893.5), (2718642119, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.53), (2718642118, 1696657969146, 0.00069, 27893.6), (2718642117, 1696657969146, 0.00025, 27893.64), (2718642116, 1696657969146, 0.00035, 27893.66), (2718642115, 1696657969146, 0.00036, 27893.67)]
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Q10.png
````